# Load Data in webservice in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, asynchronous

I'm a newbie in IOS and i'm in small project. In my project i have to load data from Webservice (SOAP) in main controller -> put Data to seacond controller.
So, maybe the data load in background thread, the method put data run before the load method. So how i can fix it?
this is my code:

```
class MainRevealController: SWRevealViewController {
var conectData:ConnectData = ConnectData()
var menuTitle:[String] = []
var menuIcon:[String] = []
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.conectData.DemoSVNew("", key: "", commandType: "Menu", version: "") { (stringData) in
        print("Hello I'm Loading Data")
        let dataArray = stringData.componentsSeparatedByString("|")
        let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: dataArray[2], options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
        let decodedString = NSString(data: decodedData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let dataArr = decodedString!.componentsSeparatedByString("<row>")
        for i in 0...dataArr.count-1 {
            let menu = dataArr[i].componentsSeparatedByString("|")
            self.menuTitle.append(menu[3])
            self.menuIcon.append(menu[4])
        }
        print("LoadData :",self.menuIcon.count)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "sw_rear" {
        let mSegue = segue.destinationViewController as! MenuController
        mSegue.menuTitle = menuTitle
        mSegue.menuIcon = menuIcon
        print("icon :",self.menuIcon.count)
        print("title :",self.menuIcon.count)
    }
}
```

this is the code show : 
[image]

Comment: What has to be fixed? What is expected to happen and what actualy happens?

Comment: i wanna fix data will be put to seacond controller after finish method download data

Comment: Again: What has to be fixed? What is expected to happen and what actualy happens?

Comment: i think u have try to use viewWillAppear() method instead of viewdidload

Comment: @Darko : in my project, i wanna download data from service, after that put it into anorther screen. But in my code it put data before download data form service -> data is empty. I wanna fix it put data after finish downloading data from service

Comment: move your API call code to "sw_rear" ViewController's `viewDidLoad` method, your API invocation and loading of "sw_rear" controller happens togather, thats why you don't get data in second controller. I hope you understood.

Comment: can you give me full code? @Dipen Panchasara

Comment: move your API call code to `MenuController`'s `viewDidLoad` method and remove it from  `MainRevealController`. Nothing else you need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make following changes in `MainRevealController`.

```
class MainRevealController: SWRevealViewController {
      override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // *** Removed your API call from here as before it returns result you are on `MenuController` ***
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "sw_rear" {
            let mSegue = segue.destinationViewController as! MenuController
            // *** No need to pass data here, as your data is loaded in `MenuController` itself ***
        }
    }
}
```

and following changes in `MenuController`.

```
class MenuController {

    var conectData:ConnectData = ConnectData()
    var menuTitle:[String] = []
    var menuIcon:[String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // *** Call your API here for menu items and perform action on result ***
        self.conectData.DemoSVNew("", key: "", commandType: "Menu", version: "") { (stringData) in
            print("Hello I'm Loading Data")
            let dataArray = stringData.componentsSeparatedByString("|")
            let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: dataArray[2], options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
            let decodedString = NSString(data: decodedData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let dataArr = decodedString!.componentsSeparatedByString("<row>")
            for i in 0...dataArr.count-1 {
                let menu = dataArr[i].componentsSeparatedByString("|")
                self.menuTitle.append(menu[3])
                self.menuIcon.append(menu[4])
            }
            print("LoadData :",self.menuIcon.count)

            // *** Do somethign with your API result ***
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

I hope its clear to you now. Happy coding :)

Comment: I did your code and it's not working. because i have to download "Menu Title" and "MenuIcon" form webservice and set it into menuViewController. 
if i use your code MenuViewController will run "cellForRowAtIndexPath" before i have data.

Comment: Its clearly written you need to perform action once your API respond. You need to set everything after your API respond, even reload your table.

Comment: can you give me an example :( , i'm very new in swift (one week) , So thank you very much

Comment: it is already there you just need to reload your table after `print("LoadData :",self.menuIcon.count)` line, `tableView.reloadData()` nothing else. i can't write whole example, pls try it yourself.

Comment: OMG, it's working, thank you very much, you save me !

Comment: Wonderful @EvanNgo put your efforts don't ask for everything. Happy coding :)